# Chrome print tables, some rows have a random height?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-tables

As you can see in these printscreens, some rows have a random height, which is obviously not what was intended.

[image]

- it is working fine in MS IE and Firefox, but not in chrome
- the affected rows seem to be random(not always the same rows)

HTML/CSS of the invoice:

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with invoice that have this random height?

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq62r/2/) for `user1609180`, but I can't seem to replicate the issue.

Comment: Well the printscreen I attached is actually from the fiddle..

Comment: Is the screenshot from the fiddle? But the fiddle only goes up to line number 199; your screenshot has lines above 200.

Comment: @Mr_Lister I think it's pretty obvious that I didn't take a screenshot of 250 lines..

Comment: @IanClark ; this is your fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Uq62r/2/show/

If I print it, it looks like this again: http://puu.sh/3tbH3.png

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - it just happens in print view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Uq62r/5/) I've tried to replace your inline styling with a stylesheet for clarity. I've also removed the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding`, and set the table CSS style of `border-collapse:collapse`. I'm not exactly sure which one of these was the culprit, but this seems to work. I've also removed your body width, as the browser should print it out at 100% anyway. Your new CSS looks like this:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#replaced {
    border:2px solid #000;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
#replaced th {
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-left:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#replaced td {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
#after td { 
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-left:none;
}
```

Where `#replaced` is your new main table, and `#after` represents the top row with "Stuff" written in it.

Comment: Thanks alot Ian! This seems to have fixed it, I'm still wondering what the problem can be though..

Comment: I suppose my advice would be (in a situation such as this) trial and error - take things out until it breaks. In general I wouldn't use a solution like you've used because inline styling isn't a great thing to do, but more importantly the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` properties are pretty much redundant now. General advise would be to stay away from poor / redundant practices and you're less prone to errors :)